# Execute custom JavaScript code after Webform has been submited with Webform Ajax Module

Tags: 7, ajax, webforms

I have an Webform that uses [Webform Ajax](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_ajax) modules, Steps module and few others.

I would like to execute some custom JavaScript code after the WebForm has been validted and submited.

I know I could execute custom PHP code by modyfing `function _webform_ajax_callback_completed($form, $form_state) {...}` inside of [`webform_ajax.module`](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/webform_ajax/tree/webform_ajax.module):

```
elseif ($form['#node']->webform['webform_ajax'] == WEBFORM_AJAX_CONFIRM){
...
//my custom code
...
```

**But I don't want to mess with this module's code.** And I want to execute JavaScript not PHP code.

Is there an way to do so, e.g. via some hook? Or maybe I can detect that form has been submited in JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

Okay, try this. After the ajax request is completed on "#myform", it runs the function.

```
$("#myform").bind('ajax:complete', function() {

     // tasks to do 


});
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11534690/how-to-do-a-jquery-callback-after-form-submit) | [API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/)

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. While this might solve the problem, it doesn't explain _why_ or _how_ it solve the problem.

Comment: Okay, updated answer